# Earthing system on a mobile vehicle?

Tags: electrical, leakage-current, grounding

We have an electrical system which needs a low impedance earthing system below two ohms. We have provided a proper earthing system
in our factory and it works well. Now my question is if the system is supposed to be mounted on a mobile vehicle what are the engineering methods to
implement earthing system?

**Edit:**  (to make it clear)
Please consider this real example in our stationary version. There is considerable electromagnetic noise in our factory which affects some signals. I removed it by using twisted shielded cables and connecting their shields to our low impedance earthing system. It decreased it to an acceptable amount. Now How can I do this in a car without a low impedance earthing system? Should I connect cable's shields to car's body? or are there any ways like this?

Comment: maybe a very very long wire? :)

Comment: Who said mobile vehicles need to be earthed? I think you'll want to be more explicit with the context of your question.

Comment: I suggest you remove the last sentence as seeking product recommendations is likely to get your question closed.

Comment: @Bort mobile vehicles do not need to be earthed. I have an electrical device needing a low impedance earth to remove leakage current or induced voltage caused by its operation.

Comment: Pana, please be explicit. What device do you have and how do you know it "needs" a low impedance earth? If you want us to guess the details, our answer may not be accurate as per your situation.

Comment: You could always operate the device inside a faraday cage...

Comment: @Bort it is not an out-of-the-box product. We designed it for our costumer. For example we have an accurate amplifier being really sensitive to noise or some sensitive voltages. We found that when we use a earth system below 2 ohms the noise will be significantly eliminated. My question is about providing that earth system in a car, nothing else!

Comment: The problem is that normally you're powering the device from mains AC voltage (I'm *guessing*), which has a connection to earth in the first place because that is provided by a power plant. If you're powering it from a vehicle, earth isn't even part of the system. So it's possible that it doesn't actually need a good earth connection, but I don't know because I don't have many details. I don't even know how you're powering it (12VDC from the car battery? 120VAC inverter?? Who knows.).

Comment: @Pana you are talking about a system on a vehicle and to call it earth is to misrepresent what you probably need given your described device's limitations. It sounds like you need some form of star-point wiring system that returns the most negative terminal of your device to the vehicle battery - this is not adequately represented by calling it an earth so, describe what your requirements are technically please.

Comment: The problem with your question is that asking about **earth** for a mobile system **does not make sense**. Do not use the word **earth** if you mean some kind of common reference that **is not** connected to the planet's soil.

Comment: @Bort you are right. I am going to use a diesel generator to power it.

Comment: So, on a "mobile vehicle" you are going to have a "diesel generator" to power a device "we designed". There is a lot of missing information in your question.

Comment: @Andy aka please consider this real example in our stationary version. There is considerable Electromagnetic  noise in our factory. I removed it by using twisted shielded cables and connecting its shield to our low impedance earthing system. it removed it in an acceptable amount. Now How can I do this in a car without out a low impedance earthing system? Should I connect it to car`s body?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: Pana, I'm giving up. If you want help, provide all details. A "diesel generator" isn't enough. Describe how your device is powered in the factory. (AC/DC? Voltage? Wiring diagram?) Also describe how you have it powered in your "mobile vehicle". (AC/DC? Voltage? Wiring diagram?) "twisted shielded cables" doesn't describe much either. What is the shield connected to? Earth and what else? The device? What part of the device? What is in the core of the twisted cables? What is anything?! I don't feel like guessing. Put effort in to your question if you want effort in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that "ground/earth" has different meanings in different contexts.  Earth means *the* earth, and ground can mean "0V reference point", "low impedance path for return current", "equipment bond", or "the ground/earth" in different contexts.  I believe for your shield to work correctly it should be connected to the ground of the vehicle, with all of the other relevant concerns of using shielding(ground loops etc.) still applying, which should also be the ground reference of your equipment's power source, if it is separate from the vehicle's already grounded alternator.  Your shield/drain should be connected to the ground that the wires it protects are referenced to.  Normally the connection would be on the upstream end for consistency/simplicity and a drain connection terminal would be provided on the board/device that the other wires terminate to.  Note that some vehicles for whatever reason are + ground instead of - ground.

If anything outboard the vehicle is not safe voltage and powered from the source(think of a diesel generator providing temporary power to a construction site), grounding rods/plates in accordance with local regulations will be used.  If all power consumption is onboard, you may not need a connection to *the* earth, in cases where this *is* needed, a sacrificial conductor is often dragged beneath the vehicle, although 2 ohms would I think be a very low impedance and as far as I recall, this is used more for static prevention when transporting explosive or flammable liquids/gases.  If you are providing power to outboard devices it is crucial that your ground connection be of sufficiently low impedance to allow the safety devices (overcurrent breaker and GFCI) to trip within spec, and this is why safety regulations will require a grounding rod/plate.

Answer (score 0):

A copper twisted cable will be rolled on a reel / wheel. One end will be connected to the earthing strip. Other end will have a grounding rod. Whenever vehicle is used for operation like Dsng etc Rod is digged in soil/ earth to achieve 0 V reference.